# Getting condition issue in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
create table testing
(
cola varchar(10),
colb varchar(10)
);

insert into testing values('A','B');
insert into testing values('C','D');
insert into testing values('C','X');
insert into testing values('S','T');
insert into testing values('S','Q');
insert into testing values('M','N');

cola   colb
-----------
 A      B
 C      D
 C      X
 S      T
 S      Q
 M      N
```

And the expected result is 1:1 ratio that is `A : B` where A is not repeated in next rows.

```
cola   colb
-----------
 A      B
 M      N
```

I am not getting how to get such condition using PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. Do you want some uniqueness constraint?

Comment: @bereal, Yes! Exactly.

Comment: Could you elaborate, what do you what to restrict: `(A, B), (A, C)` (unique `cola`) or `(A, B), (A, B)` (unique, `cola, colb`)?

Comment: I want to restrict only `(A,B)` not `(A,C)`.

Comment: So, to rephrase, you want `(A, B)` to occur no more than once, and the rest of the values can be whatever one needs?

Comment: Yes! but in future if i get `(M,N)` then I have to show it because of uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the optimal way, but will definitely work:

```
SELECT cola, colb FROM testing WHERE cola IN
    (SELECT cola FROM testing GROUP BY cola HAVING count(*)=1);

 cola | colb
------+------
 A    | B
 M    | N
```